# Ansible: How to deal with quotes and spaces using shell

Tags: linux, ansible, redhat, quotes

I'm creating a playbook to list the users in the "/home" directory using the folowing playbook on ansible 2.8.2:

```
---
- name: Check users in /home directory
  hosts: REDHAT
  tasks:
  - name: List users
      shell: cat /etc/passwd | grep "/home" |cut -d ":" -f1| tr '\n' ' '
      register: output
      ignore_errors: yes
```

The problem i have is at the end of the command with the quotes and spaces: `'\n' ' '`

i have tried to use double quotes `", {} and []` but yet im still having syntax errors

The results when i use  `---syntax-check`:

```
> The offending line appears to be:

  - name: List users
      shell: cat /etc/passwd | grep "/home" |cut -d ":" -f1| tr "'\n' ' '"
           ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
unbalanced quotes. If starting a value with a quote, make sure the
line ends with the same set of quotes. For instance this arbitrary
example:

    foo: "bad" "wolf"

Could be written as:

    foo: '"bad" "wolf"'
```

When do i exactly have to use the quotes in this case

Answer (score 1):

Take Y minutes to read [Learn yaml in Y minute](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/) where you will learn that:

> [Yaml is] a strict superset of JSON, with the addition of syntactically significant newlines and indentation, like Python. Unlike Python, however, YAML doesn’t allow literal tab characters for indentation.

Your problem is not at all with quotes but with indentation of your code in your shell task:

```
---
- name: Check users in /home directory
  hosts: REDHAT
  tasks:
    - name: List users
      shell: cat /etc/passwd | grep "/home" |cut -d ":" -f1| tr '\n' ' '
      register: output
      ignore_errors: yes
```

Note that using [yamllint](https://pypi.org/project/yamllint/) on your above file gives a slightly more precise error:

```
$ yamllint playbook_test.yml 
playbook_test.yml
  6:12      error    syntax error: mapping values are not allowed here
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Zeitounator's reply, use the modules that are shipped with Ansible. That way you can use the function later with non-RHEL OS's as well. Also, if there would be a change to the output the script won't start failing.

In this case I'd recommend the getent module:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/getent_module.html